# Angular Reactive Forms: trigger validation on component on page load

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

I have an Angular Reactive Form and the validators like `required` only triggers when I enter them and then leave, or after `submit` button is pressed.

I want to trigger those validators right after page loads (values are passed to the form fields) in order to show user that the pre-filled controls are invalid, and display the error messages underneath each input in case they are invalid.

Comment: please add some code to understand your problem

Comment: The question is very simple to understand and it is a very important task that has to be made in angular apps that edits data forms that came from backend.

Answer (score 1):

after create the form

```
setTimeout(()=>{
   this.myForm.patchValue(this.myForm.value)
})
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what I've been looking for in a long time!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following way,

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.TestForm.InputText.setValidators([Validators.required]);
}



<form [formGroup]="TestForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label id="testInput" class="form-label">Input</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="InputText" name="testInput" id="testInput">
        <div class="form-control" *ngIf="TestForm?.InputText?.invalid">
            <p class="error" *ngIf="TestForm?.InputText?.errors?.required"> Required </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```